# While loop inside recursive function failed if looped more than once

Tags: node.js, loops, recursion, while-loop

My code below runs fine if the while loop condition is < 6 (i.e. one loop), but failed if it is set to < 7 or more (i.e. more than 1 loop)

```
var data = {
    a: "abc",
    c: 0
}

function recurse(data, nodes) {
    const first = nodes.shift();
    console.log("first-"+first.id, first.t);

    if (first.t == "action") {
        data.c = data.c + 1;
        console.log("exec action", data.c);
    } else {
        switch (first.t) {
            case "if_else":
                console.log(recurse(data, first.b[0].actions), 300);
                break
            case "while":
                var brNodes = first.b[0].actions
                while (data.c < 7) {
                  console.log(recurse(data, brNodes), 400);
                }
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    
    return (nodes.length > 0)? console.log(recurse(data, nodes), 200): "Completed"
} 

var actions = [
    {id:1, t:"action", b:null},
    {id:2, t:"action", b:null},
    {id:3, t:"if_else", b:[{id:31, t:"branch", actions:[{id:311, t:"action", b:null}, {id:312, t:"action", b:null}]},{id:32, t:"branch", actions:[{id:321, t:"action", b:null}]}]},
    {id:4, t:"action", b: null},
    {id:5, t:"while", b:[{id:500, t:"branch", actions:[{id:511, t:"action", b:null}]}]},
    {id:6, t:"action", b:null}
]

console.log(recurse(data, actions), 100)
```

Here is my testing on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/recurse?file=index.js

Comment: I didn't see any `data.c` field in your `actions`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon - `data` and `data.c` are defined at the beginning of the OP's code block.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

looks like i have figured it out myself... the array was passed in by reference, and after the first loop it was consumed to an empty array. i replaced it with [...] spread

console.log(recurse(data, [...first.b[0].actions]), 400);

and this should solved

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing this:

```
const first = nodes.shift();
```

And, then attempting to access:

```
 first.b[0].actions
```

And, `nodes.shift()` removes the first element from the `nodes` array.  Your nodes array has 6 items.  If you try to call your function 7 times by setting the condition to `while (data.c < 7)`, you will end up with an empty `nodes` array and thus an `undefined` value in `first` on the last iteration and that will cause an error when your code attempts to access `first.b[0].actions` on the last iteration.

Comment: @kkgan - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.